# An arrow between two tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, arrows

How can I display an arrow between two `tikzpictures` (of the same size) so that the arrow is alligned with the centre of the pictures?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  tlabel/.style={pos=0.4,right=-1pt},
]
\node{$\Rightarrow$}
child {node {$\wedge$}
child {node {$p$}}
child {node {$q$}}}
child {node {$r$}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

 $\rightarrow$ % the arrow between the pictures

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  tlabel/.style={pos=0.4,right=-1pt},
]
\node{$\Rightarrow$}
child {node {$\wedge$}
child {node {$p$}}
child {node {$q$}}}
child {node {$r$}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative generic solution with adjustbox: [Forest trees on the same line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146568/forest-trees-on-the-same-line) for top alignment or [vertical alignment - Aligning several forest trees in centered way - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206728/aligning-several-forest-trees-in-centered-way/206731#206731) for center alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: arrow between]

This uses the `baseline` key with the value `(current bounding box.center)` to align the centres of the pictures with the current baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    tlabel/.style={pos=0.4,right=-1pt},
    baseline=(current bounding box.center)
    ]
    \node{$\Rightarrow$}
    child {node {$\wedge$}
      child {node {$p$}}
      child {node {$q$}}}
    child {node {$r$}}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  $\rightarrow$ % the arrow between the pictures
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    tlabel/.style={pos=0.4,right=-1pt},
    baseline=(current bounding box.center)
    ]
    \node{$\Rightarrow$}
    child {node {$\wedge$}
      child {node {$p$}}
      child {node {$q$}}}
    child {node {$r$}}
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you are drawing trees, you should consider one of the specialised libraries or packages as they offer greater power and flexibility and, in many cases, a syntax which allows you to specify a tree much more concisely.

Packages include `forest` (based on TikZ), `tikz-qtree` (obviously TikZ-based), `qtree` (non-TikZ) and the TikZ library `trees` (much less powerful and does not support specialised syntax).

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thanks! I tried some tree packages but they didn't display the trees how I want. I only need to draw a few simple trees and tikz seems fine for that.

Comment: @notnek Certainly if it works for you, there is no need to fix it ;).