# Place an arithmetic symbol between two bar charts in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, axis

I want to visualize a calculation based on two bar charts. For this I want to draw two bar charts side by side and a multiplication sign between both of them.

I wanted both axis environments and the multiplication sign to be nodes that I could position relative to each other using the positioning library but I noticed that the axis environments don't have a name that I could bind to.

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260587/an-arrow-between-two-tikzpictures) does the trick if everything is in one line. Positioning something below a chart would not be possible.

Is there a way to use relative positioning in my case?

Comment: Could you add a MWE?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with this abbreviation. What's a MWE?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template for your answer could start with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=a,
at ={(0,0)}%this was intentional ;)
]

\end{axis},
\node[right = 1cm of a] (b){$\times$};
\node[right = 1cm of b] (c){};
\begin{axis}[name=d,
at={(c.center)},
anchor=left of west,
]
\end{axis},
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

Now, I hope you can start filling in the missing blanks to get whatever you need ;) happy `Tikzing`!