# How to center vertically arrow between two Ferrer's diagrams

Tags: vertical-alignment, youngtab

I need to draw two Ferrer's diagrams with right arrow between them. I do it like so

```
\usepackage{youngtab}
$ \young(~,~,~,~~,~~,~~~) \longrightarrow \young(~,~,~,~,~~,~~,~~) $
```

[image: Arrow between two Ferrer's diagrams]

But the arrow is drawn at the bottom of diagrams. How to center it vertically?

UPD: Preferably I need diagrams to stay aligned to the bottom, but the arrow must be centered. Also it should work for diagrams of any height without me having to correct a lot of code.

Comment: Probably `\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}` helps. This will however also change the alignment of the two young tableaus.

Comment: @leandriis this is sublime, I like it

Comment: Future visitors might be looking for [tikz pgf - An arrow between two tikzpictures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260587/an-arrow-between-two-tikzpictures) for TikZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `youngtab` package offers the `vcentermath` package option in order to vertically center insisde of math mode.

Adding this option to the package results in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}
\begin{document}
\[\young(~,~,~,~~,~~,~~~) \longrightarrow \young(~,~,~,~,~~,~~,~~) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good, but still does not solve the whole problem, I updated question with a remark.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the many possibilities using a `matrix` between the Young tableaux. If you want put the horizontal arrow above, you can add `& \\`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{youngtab}

\begin{document}

$ \young(~,~,~,~~,~~,~~~) \begin{matrix}  \longrightarrow &  \\& \\& \\& \\ & \\ & \end{matrix}\young(~,~,~,~,~~,~~,~~) $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite ingenious!

Comment: @Bernard LoL   ...But it is not true....

Comment: But what if I need to draw another pair of diagrams with another height? I will need to rewrite matrix

Comment: @ReFruity Yes, with my code....but I not knew nothing for this package. I will switch for the answer of very nice user leandriis. It is the best. Can you give the check mark, please, to user leandriis?